# Error when clicking resolve button when adding a calendar overlay

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation

We get the following error message

> Feature '75a0fea7-625d-4b31-be9e-24cee53d0d72' for list template '1009' is not installed in this farm. The operation could not be completed.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is migrated site( from 2007) because the `AssetTrackingAssetsList(75a0fea7-625d-4b31-be9e-24cee53d0d7)` is part of fab 40 packages in Moss 2007.

- Now either you need to [upgrade and deploy](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2010/08/18/sharepoint-2010-products-upgrade-and-the-fabulous-40-application-templates.aspx) that package in 2010 if you
  are still using that template.
- Or you can use the SharePoint admin tool to clean up the stuff from
  the site collection. here is the tool from [codeplex](http://spm.codeplex.com/releases/view/97332)

http://teonedev.blogspot.com/2012/04/fab40not-so-fabulous-after-sharepoint.html

Answer (score 0):

Feature with ID `75a0fea7-625d-4b31-be9e-24cee53d0d72` is missing in your farm.

This feature represent Site Feature `AssetTrackingAssetsList` and is available in solution `ApplicationTemplateCore.wsp`.

So to resolve you should deploy that solution into the farm.